# removing .php extension from .htaccess (404?)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to removing .php extension from the url using .htaccess i've found a view sites that told me how to do this and i'm using;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However when i go to mydomain.com/user/settings (that would be mydomain.com/user/settings.php without the .htaccess)

It works fine. However when i go to mydomain.com/user/settings/ (trending splash on the end) it gives my custom 404 error page i've looked around on here (& Similar Questions) ask and google but can't really seem to work out what part i'm missing out?

Thank You,
Flexer

Answer (score 1):

Try this to handle the trailing slash

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks however that didn't do anything i got it working with RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]. ** UPDATE** nvm that only works if it has a traiing slash on the end now..

Comment: Try the updated rule needed to make the first section non greedy